Unable to Establish Connection Between Vue and Go Using Socket.IO
I'm trying to set up a connection between a Vue frontend and a Go backend using Socket.IO. I'm using socket.io-client version 4.7.5 in Vue and github.com/googollee/go-socket.io in Go.
Here's the relevant code:
Vue (HomeView.vue):
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
import { io, Manager } from 'socket.io-client'

onBeforeMount(() => {
  console.log('init')
  const url = "http://localhost:8000"
  const manager = new Manager(url)

  const socket = manager.socket("/") // main namespace

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Socket.IO server')
  })

  socket.emit('hello', { a: 'b', c: '1' })
  socket.emit('notice', 'Hallo')
  socket.emit('bye', 'bye')

  socket.on('hey', (...args) => {
    console.log(args)
  })
})
</script>

Go (main.go):
func CORSHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            return
        }

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    server := socketio.NewServer(nil)
    fmt.Println("connected:")

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        fmt.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        return nil
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        fmt.Println("notice:", msg)
        s.Emit("reply", "have "+msg)
    })

    server.OnEvent("/chat", "msg", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) string {
        s.SetContext(msg)
        return "recv " + msg
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "bye", func(s socketio.Conn) string {
        last := s.Context().(string)
        s.Emit("bye", last)
        s.Close()
        return last
    })

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", CORSHandler(server))
    log.Println("Serving at localhost:8000...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}

Issue:
When I try to connect, I receive the following error in the browser console:
Error: server error
    at _Socket.onPacket (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:1519:23)
    at Emitter.emit (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:354:21)
    at Polling.onPacket (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:538:11)
    at callback (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:726:12)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Polling.onData (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:728:49)
    at Emitter.emit (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:354:21)
    at _Request.onLoad (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:946:12)
    at xhr.onreadystatechange (socket__io-client.js?v=76825f20:889:16)

I've ensured that the server is running and accessible at http://localhost:8000. The CORS settings seem correct as well. What could be causing this connection issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I expect to be able to connect to socketio and send and receive data

You are connecting to http://localhost:8000 but your server is running at http://localhost:8000/socket.io/! Apart from that change socket.io to hub that makes more sense.
